# Symfony 2.8 access control

Tags: symfony

I have the following in my access control section

```
access_control:
  - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
  - { path: ^/(.*), roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I thought this would mean that my base url, and login screen wouldn't require the ROLE_USER but all other routes would require the user to be logged in. However this doesn't look to be the case as all routes seem to be AUTHENTICATED ANONYMOUSLY

I'm sure there's something simple i'm missing but any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following codes. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

By the above code, the login and only home path will accessible by anonymous user. Any other link will be accessible only if the user has some rules. But I believe you may have a register link and forgot password link. Both register and forgot password links should be accessible by all users. So don't forget to keep those urls in the 2nd line.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Helo

All Access controls runs top-down.

Symfony checks current route with  access  control one-by-one  from top to down.

And if it's  match then don't check the rest.

move

```
- { path: ^/(.*), roles: ROLE_USER }
```

to top as a  first condition

Comment: I've changed the access control as suggested to move to the top however now the base URL routes through to the login page and firefox displays the following message: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: if this not worked for you , then show your whole  security.yml

Comment: redirect loop -   you need to have login and  login check as IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY

Comment: look  at https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html    section "Avoid Common Pitfalls"

Comment: i believe the loop will be because the regular expression now moved to the top as the line at the top now includes the /login. I will post my security.yml

Answer (score 0):

your two lines point at the same URL patterns, so there is a conflict :

```
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(.*), roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Try this one :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```